# How to Convert String of DateTime to Date and 24 hour formate Time in android?

Tags: android, datetime

I have a string holding a Date and time I want to be able to strip out the AM - and the PM and convert all the times to 24 hour format so 9:30PM would really be 21:30 .

Im having this code which im trying to convert into specific formate but cant get the proper result

```
  String DateTime="14/03/2012 12:32:38 PM";

   format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
            try {
                date=format1.parse(TransactionDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

 After that im trying to convert date in yyyy-MM-dd and time in 24 Hour format but im not getting proper result.

     format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            TransDateTime=format1.format(date);
```

im getting result is 2012-03-14 12:32:38 PM but i want time in 24 hour formate date is correct but time not in 24 hour format .

Sorry this is commom question but i try all the solutions and result is same can any buddy tell me whats the problem .

Comment: 12:32 is in 24hours format.. Please check for any value 01.00pm if it will not give you 13.00 then only you can say your result is wrong

Comment: yes after 1 PM it Gives me 13:00 but what about 12:32 it should be 00:32 .

Answer (score 1):

Please use following code, it will solve your problem,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Make a String that has a date in it, with MEDIUM date format
    // and SHORT time format.
    String dateString = "Nov 4, 2003 8:14 PM";

    // Get the default MEDIUM/SHORT DateFormat
    DateFormat format =
        DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
        DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT);

    // Parse the date
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println("Original string: " + dateString);
        System.out.println("Parsed date    : " +
             date.toString());
    }
    catch(ParseException pe) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: could not parse date in string \"" +
            dateString + "\"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the hour in 24 hours format you have to use

> " H:mm";

as pattern

Comment: Not getting proper result ,same result 2012-03-14 12:32

Comment: well that depends. 12:32 is in 24hours format.. if it show 13:00 as 1 PM you can say "not getting proper result"..

Comment: But after 12 PM it should be 00:32 PM

Comment: yes it has.. sorry I have not ask you if you meas 12 am or pm in my previous comment.. It is a bit strange. The docs says "H  Hour in day (0-23) " so your code looks good to me...

Comment: Hey after 1 PM it shows me 13:00:00 PM but what about after 12 PM it should be 00:32 PM

Comment: Sorry its my mistake it is DateTime not TransactionDate

Comment: then i think the 11:59 PM should give you 23:50 and 12:32 AM should give you 00:32

Comment: yes i got it after 23:59 PM should give you 24:00 pm after that 00:1 AM and in afternoon after 12 it should give you 12:59 PM after that 13:00 PM because using HH:mm give you (0-23) and using kk:mm gives you (1-24)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8859/discussion-between-sachin-gurnani-and-blackbelt)